# How can I filter my blog list

Tags: joomla-3.x, tags

By default when I type in sitename/blog I get all the articles with the category of blog. I would like to be able to filter this list by the tags associated with each blog item but I cannot find how to do this.

I can see how I can use modules to display but i want the actual component to be filtered. Could someone please tell me how this can be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean "by default when I type in sitename/blog...". Can you explain better the setup of your site. In addition a link to your website would be helpful.

Comment: I just mean the normal process is when you type in site/blog you see all the articles from the category of blog. I want to somehow filter this list so that I only, for example, see the articles with the category of blog and have been tagged UK

Comment: Sorry, but it still makes no sense to me. I asked what you mean with that sentence, and you replied using that same sentence twice. Consider to improve your question, to describe better how you have setup your site and what you want to do. What you have done and what you want to do, is unclear, in your current question. For example: I use the X component's menu item to show a these Y items in a V layout. I am also using a Tags system for these items... I want to display a filter on top of that to... etc... As said links to your pages, screenshots etc can help.

Comment: Sorry, you have trouble understanding English. Default means 'out of the box' or 'as it comes'.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla Content component does not provide a way to filter by fixed tags in a menu item.

You can implement an extension for extended tags options. For example, K2 does have: **Tag** *Create a menu item linking to a tag in K2.*

Comment: Thanks for that. I was hoping there might be some way to do this without having to create a new menu page for each tag. Not quite sure how it would but I guess something along the lines of how the search feature works.